# PL sql code to check if record in one column exist in same order as record in another column of different tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

Suppose I have two below tables data and I want to check if record in one column exist in same order as record in another column of different tables

```
table 1
column A
1
2
3

table2
column A
1
1
3
3
3
2
2
```

Comment: Rows in a relation database have no implied "order", so you can't test whether one row has the same "order" as another (and a **single** row can never have "an order" to begin with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it,

ROWID:ROWID is a pseudo column in a table which store and return row address in HEXADECIMAL format with database tables.ROWID is the permanent unique identifiers for each row in the database. 
ROWID consists of 18 character string with the format. BBBBBBBBB.RRRR.FFFF Where B is Block, R is Row, F is File.

Query below would work assuming you don't perform any deletion as oracle reuses the address in the event of deletion.

```
 select orderedtable1.columnA,orderedtable1.rn 
    from
    (select columnA, row_number() over(order by rowid) rn 
     from table2)  orderedtable2,
    (select columnA, row_number() over(order by rowid) rn 
    from table1) orderedtable1
    where orderedtable1.columnA=orderedtable2.columnA
    and orderedtable1.rn = orderedtable2.rn
```

Output :

```
COLUMNA RN
    1        1
    3        3
```

ROWNUM:For each row returned by a query, the ROWNUM pseudo column returns a number which indicates the order in which a row was selected from a table.ROWNUM is valid only for that session of that query as it changes as the records gets inserted/modified in the table.

Below query would work provided you don't have any index as the default ordering of select is by the way the records are inserted since you don't have any index/constraints on the table in which case the output would differ.

```
select orderedtable1.columnA,orderedtable1.rn 
from
(select columnA, rownum rn 
 from table2)  orderedtable2,
(select columnA, rownum rn 
from table1) orderedtable1
where orderedtable1.columnA=orderedtable2.columnA
and orderedtable1.rn = orderedtable2.rn
```

Output:

```
COLUMNA RN
1        1
3        3
```

For more details on the solution refer the dbfiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b76134a6d6c204faa994f534ac89d1b0

Comment: Rowid / row address have no inherent value related to row "order".  It can't, because in a heap table 'row order' has no meaning at all. You might be able to use rowid to deduce something about the chornological order in which rows were inserted, but that does not mean that it matches to the OP's concept of 'row order'.  In addition look at the impact of row migration on 'rowid', and the implications of using rowid as some sort of pseudo row order.

Comment: @Edstevens - I completely agree to your point, Untill OP provide more details on what "order" means complete solution cannot be provide. There are exceptional scenarios where these wouldn't work, will wait for more details.Do you want me to make changes to my answer in current context?

Comment: whether you modify your answer is up to you.  I'd hope that our follow-on comments would be sufficient, but who knows?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check if record in one column exist in same order as record in another column of different tables

Standard Oracle table is a `heap-organized` table. It is a table with rows stored in **no particular order**, rows are inserted where they fit.